# unable to get POST data in php 'undefined index' error

Tags: php, ajax

I am using plain javascript for Ajax request. when sending data by post method php throwing an error.

index.php

```
<html>

    <header>

        <script>
            function submit(){

                var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var passWord = document.getElementById("password").value;


                var data = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord;

                //send ajax request
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.open("post", "validateuser.php");
                xmlHttp.send(data);
            }
        </script>

    </header>

    <body>

            <label>User Name : </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>

            <label>Password : </label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>

            <button onClick="submit()"> Login</button>

    </body>

</html>
```

validateuser.php

```
<?php

    $userName = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

echo $userName . $password;
```

Comment: what is the message in console log of browser?

Comment: What does your browser console say? Does it show that it successfully posted to `validateuser.php`? Does it show the `data` value as posted?

Comment: its out put php error. sayin `</span> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\redstone\formsapp\validateuser.php on line <i>3</i>` and `</span> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\redstone\formsapp\validateuser.php on line <i>4</i>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript ajax for post you need to add following line in your code:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

You can check documentation and example [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) and [developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

And for more reliable code just add following line to your php code

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
     //your code
}
```

Comment: Using jquery's `$.ajax()` for so long, I forgot about this. Nice catch! +1 (although I would recommend linking to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started instead of w3schools)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the headers on your `xmlHttp` object. Add the following line before `xmlHttp.send(data);` line :

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```